# Fibonacci sequence in a vector

Tags: c++, vector, fibonacci

I was thinking about the complexity of the recursive approach to the fibonnaci sequence and i wanted to try storing the numbers in a vector so that my program can look at the last two numbers the vector contains to produce the next. I wrote a procedure that i thought would append the next number to the fibs vector using a pointer to the vectors last element, but nothing happens (when i print the vector after calling the procedure, it still only contains 0 and 1 i appended manualy as the edge condition.

Is this a scope issue?

```
vector<int>fibs;
template <typename Iterator>
void newfib(Iterator it) {
   fibs.push_back(*(it-1)+*(it-2));
 }     

int main () {

vector<int>fibs;
fibs.push_back(0); fibs.push_back(1);
newfib(fibs.end());
return 0;
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You have two vectors there, both called fibs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare two verctors with same name: one in global scope, second in main function. In function `newfib` you append to global vector, but in main function you print local, which stays unchanged.

I suggest avoid using global variables and pass vector by refernece, for example.

Answer (score 0):

It's a scope issue. `newfib` only knows the global `fibs` object. `main` operates on the local `fibs` object.

Answer (score 0):

The `fibs` vector declared inside `main()` hides the one declared globally within the `main()` function.  However, within the `newfib()` function, the global `fibs` vector is used instead.

The simplest fix here is to remove the `fibs` declaration within `main()`.  However, this code needs a lot of work before it's ready for prime time.

Answer (score 0):

There are two vector objects with *same* name `fibs` — one at namespace level, and other one in `main()` function.

Whatever you do  in `newfib()` function, does NOT change the object `fibs` in the `main()` function, for it is *local* and `newfib()` modifies the *global* one.